# Date.js: Date.now() behaving oddly

Tags: javascript, date, datejs

I'm using [date.js.](http://www.datejs.com/)

The line `time_container.innerHTML = Date.now().toString('T');` worked fine, briefly, and is now throwing errors in the Firebug console: `radix must be an integer at least 2 and no greater than 36`. It was certainly working earlier.

Note: The date.js `toString()` function uses special [format specifiers](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers).

```
var show_date = {
    setup: function() {
        setInterval(show_date.update, 5000);
    },
    update: function() {
        var date_container = app.get('js_date');
        var time_container = app.get('js_time');

        if (date_container) {
            date_container.innerHTML = Date.today().toString('dS of MMMM yyyy');
        }
        if (time_container) {
            //time_container.innerHTML = Date.now().toString('T');
            var d1 = new Date();
            time_container.innerHTML = d1.toString('T');
        }
    }
}
app.onload(show_date.setup);
```

`app.get()` is just a shortcut for `document.getElementById()`. `app.onload()` is (as you might guess) an onload function.

Commented out line is causing the problems. Replacement lines below the comment work, but don't give the format I want. `T` should output `h:mm:ss tt` (hours, minutes, seconds, am/pm). The am/pm bit is missing.

Also, I'm certain `Date.now()` was working earlier today. Perhaps I'll try playing with the computer clock to see whether that makes a difference.

Version of date.js included is `date-en-IE.js`. Claimed date in the code is 2008-05-13, even though I got it from the SVN checkout earlier today.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The argument for `toString` is the base in which you want to encode a number. For example, `toString(16)` will give you hexadecimal.

Comment: Ah, I see now that date.js has a `toString` function (http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString). Well it would appear to me that you aren't including date.js correctly if it's not working. Try doing `Date.today` in the console and see what it returns.

Comment: `Date.today()` returns `Date {Thu Sep 08 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)}` in the console. And, in the same script, `date_container.innerHTML = Date.today().toString('dS of MMMM yyyy');` works fine. The problem seems to be with `Date.now()` only.

Comment: Well I can't help more unless I see your code. Try to reproduce the problem in the smallest ammount of code possible, otherwise just post your whole thing.

Comment: @Xeon06. Further detail added.

Comment: I have no further ideas. If nobody answers here, consider asking in the mailjs mailing list (http://groups.google.com/group/datejs/topics?pli=1). Good luck.

Comment: Are you using Modernizr or some other polyfill library? Maybe you're overwriting Datejs's `Date.now` implementation with the ECMAScript 5 version.

Comment: Working from a hint in a now deleted answer, `Date.today()` is working, so date.js must be included, but `Date.now()` is giving me milliseconds instead of a date object. That's the default js behaviour, but date.js should be overriding it.

Comment: @Matthew. Simpost. Could be something like that. Mootools and jQuery are the only libraries we have here.

Comment: @TRIG: I realized the same thing, which is why I deleted my answer ;) After a little more investigation I updated/undeleted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ECMAScript 5 already has a  `Date.now()` function that returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970. You're apparently calling that version so the `toString('T')` call is on a number, not a `Date` object. `Number.prototype.toString` can only take a number from 2 to 36 as its argument, which is where the error is coming from.

After looking into it a little, it looks like the latest Datejs version doesn't add its own `Date.now()` function anymore. Maybe you were using an older version when it worked?

Try `new Date().toString('T')` instead, which should work either way.

Comment: That does work, but the second problem still applies: the date format isn't applied properly. Whether I call `T` or `h:mm:ss tt`, what I get is `HH:mm:ss`. But I suppose that's a fine detail which doesn't really matter too much.

Comment: @TRIG: I don't have an answer for that part right now. It could be a bug in Datejs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error in FireFox.
By changing .toString() method to .toDateString() seems like took care of that problem.
Example: `Date.now().toDateString('M/d/yyyy HH:mm')`