# how to convert to datetime in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datetime

I want to convert String value to datetime. Actually i have a String value( That is date) getting it from back end. And Now I want to convert it to datetime as i have to apply countdown jquery plugin for that value. And Count Down plugin takes a "**Untill**" value as parameter. So for that i want to convert it to datetime.I have tried the following code references[Jquery Function To convert Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402386/jquery-function-to-convert-datetime-split-date-time-2010-10-18-1006-to-retur),

```
 var d1 = Date.parse('2010-10-18, 10:06 AM');
  alert(d1.toString('dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT'));
```

But its giving me error "**Timestamp: 7/14/2012 3:16:05 PM
Error: radix must be an integer at least 2 and no greater than 36**". Please help me come out from this problem.

Comment: have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349284/date-js-date-now-behaving-oddly